# Can you create two distinct curves that do not overlap using a single equation in two variables in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-curves

If I graph the single equation in one variable $x^2 - 1 = 10$ in $\mathbb R$ I get two distinct points on the real line (obviously I could say the solutions don't overlap).

I'm trying to think of a single equation in two variables that when graphed in $\mathbb R^2$ gives me two distinct curves that also do not overlap.

Is this possible?  I can't think of one off the off the top of my head. May be a dumb question.

Comment: Is hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$ good enough?

Comment: How about $(x-y)^2-1=10$

Comment: Wow!  I missed the example of a hyperbola.  Ugh..  lol so  is it possible to create two distinct circles this way?

Comment: `is it possible to create two distinct circles this way` Yes, with a higher degree equation. Let $C_1 : f(x,y)=0$ and $C_2 : g(x,y) = 0$ be two arbitrary curves (including for example a pair of distinct circles). Then the curve $f(x,y) \cdot g(x,y) = 0$ is $C_1 \cup C_2$.

Comment: I usually don't follow up... but I like this answer.  Excellent!

Comment: Thanks. I shall add that my example is the direct extension of the single variable case. The reason why $x^2 - 1=10$ gives two distinct points on the real axis is that it factors as $(x - \sqrt{11}) \cdot (x + \sqrt{11}) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very possible. A simple example is $xy=1$, which is just the standard hyperbola.

You can even do it with one variable: $|x|=1$.

You can get two concentric circles around $(0, 0)$ with something like $|x^2+y^2-a|=b$.

You can get two circles next to each other with something like: $(|x|-a)^2+y^2=b$.

Comment: Thank you!  I understand them now.  Follow up...  Is it possible to create two circles side by side (not inside of each other) in the same way?

Comment: It should be. My first thought was an image I have seen of two "lying drops" pointing towards each other, but I can't remember how that is made, or what it's called.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty hard to interpret, what you mean by "gives me", if you mean a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that its intersections with the plane $z=0$ are two disjoint curves, then take a look at $z=\frac{1}{x}-y$, when $z=0$, it has

$$\frac{1}{x}-y=0 \Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{x},$$

Which are two "curves" in the form of a hyperbola.

EDIT: Here you are, it's a "vertical torus" cut at $z=0$:

$$(5-\sqrt{x^2}))^2+y^2=2^2$$

The $2$ is the radius of the circles, and the $5$ is the distance from the origin to the centres of each circle.

Comment: I apologize.  I would like to create two distinct circles (non overlapping and not one circle inside each other) graphed in $R^2$ using a single equation in only two variables x and y.

Comment: A popular example I see. To get two circles, I would find the equation for the "double torus" and lift it so that it intersects the $z$-plane in two circles.

Comment: For sure it is possible, for a price of complexity of equation, idea of NewbcakeDK is good to reduce it.

Comment: But you need to do some weird stuff to kinda "lift" it up in the middle.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain I edited my post to include an explicit formula.

Comment: Your explicit formula seems to be close to what you would get from the formula I gave in my answer if you "expand" $|x|$ to $\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: You're right about that!